# Xcode, Objective-C: Combine two images and then save them?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image

I have two images in my application. I want to create a new canvas, fit both images in it, and save it as a .png file, including transparency settings etc.

How do I do such? I mean, the part of combining them sounds puzzling..